# Close and Minimise button is disabled on Linux using Qt5.3.2

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-quick, qt5.3

I have created an application using Qt 5.3.2. When the application loads the Close and Minimize buttons appear in case of Mac and Windows, But when i run the same code on Linux these buttons are no longer available.

Can anyone point me to why this maybe happening? This is the code i use to create the main screen.

Here View is object of `QQuickView`:

```
    View view(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));

    view.setMaximumSize(QSize(1280,700));
    view.setMinimumSize(QSize(1280,700));

    // Centering the App to the middle of the screen
    int width = view.frameGeometry().width();
    int height = view.frameGeometry().height();
    QDesktopWidget wid;
    int screenWidth = wid.screen()->width();
    int screenHeight = wid.screen()->height();
    view.setGeometry((screenWidth/2)-(width/2),(screenHeight/2)-(height/2),width,height);


    view.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the windows flag for `QQuickView` as :

```
view.setFlags(Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It does work. However, can you tell me if I can disable only maximise button. Coz in Linux when i click that, it flickers a bit.

Comment: I don't see any maximize button when running your code. Do you see it when you only set the flags? Set the maximum and minimum size the same.

Comment: It works well on Linux , but on windows the buttons doesnt show up.

Comment: The do not set the flags on Windows. Use `#ifdef WIN32` to determine the OS environment.

Comment: Yes. Did that already. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.